# How do I add multiple locations on Google Maps via Telegram Bot?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, location, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to send multiple locations pinned on a single map into `telegram-bot`, by using send location function. is there a way to send multiple locations to telegram bot? I try and just can send one location to telegram bot.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide your current code, showing how you are sending a single location. Then show what you already tried for sending multiple locations, and what the output was.

Comment: i send my send request code like this
"await Bot.SendLocationAsync(message.Chat.Id,43.296482,5.369763);"
but i want to send list of long&lat to show on map

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you want to send multiple locations to the user so you don't want to put numbers in the SendLocation method. If the locations that need to be sent are some fixed locations you can save them in an array or in a DB and use a loop to send them.

But if they're not fixed you have to send them to the bot first and then force the bot to send to a user or anywhere else.(channel or group) The code below may help you:

```
//Send the location like: latitude=xxx&longtitude=yyy;
if(update.Message.Text.Contains("latitude") && update.Message.Text.Contains("longtitude"))
{
string latitude = text.Split('&').First();
string longtitude = text.Split('&').Last();
//splites the input text into two parts first part is latitude=xxx and second or last part is longtitude=yyy. because the string is splited based on & sign

float latitue_num = float.Parse(latitude.Split('=').Last());
float longtitude_num = float.Parse(longtitude.Split('=').Last());
//does the same action for "latitude=xxx" and "longtitude=yyy" after that the number xxx is stored in latitude_num and yyy is stored in longtitude_num

var req = new SendLocation(update.Message.Chat.Id, latitue_num, longtitude_num);
await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);
}
```

Of course if the number of locations is too big, it's better to use a database and send them to bot from the DB.

And if you want to send the locations from a user to the bot(not from bot to a user) you can use:

```
if(update.Message.Location != null)
{
.
.
.
//here you can do whatever you want every time bot receives a location. no matter how many locations are sent to the bot the bot will receive them one by one and do the action(s) listed in this method.
}
```

I hope these will help you, your question was not clear therefore I explained this way.

Comment: thank you from your answer but my problem was about sending multiple location in single map. i solved my problem by sending photo from map which google map create from this url https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=tehran,ir&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&key=AIzaSyC1iKAPcxTPoTFzRcIlJjw9Qj-NSSokipE

Comment: @fatememosleh This can be a good idea but it will be difficult for your bot's users that way, cause your sending just a photo, not a map or location. [This link](https://www.create.net/support/218-how-to-pin-point-multiple-locations-on-google-maps.html) may help you too. After following the steps in the link you can send your map's link in your telegram bot easily. You can name your own map and pin multiple locations on it with your favorite names.

Answer (score 0):

You Can't.
This method Just send point on the map.
Check Telegram Bot API (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendlocation)